# Detach firebase realtime database from react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As I have not used firebase realtime DB only using firestore, if I disable the realtime db from firebase console, it stops the react app from running after login is success. I do have databaseURL property in firebase config. So how to detach the realtime firebase db from the react app. So that even if I disable realtime db from firebase it shouldn't affect my app.

```js
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};

const db = app.database();
```

Comment: Could you please add your configuration snippet along with your data-mounted components and how you are initializing the `firebase` client?

Comment: Firebase SDKs should only access services that you code explicitly uses. "it stop the react app from running"  Can you explain what you mean by that? Is there an error message?

Comment: const db = app.database()
Does this refers to firebase realtime db or firestore?